# When given the soprano and bass parts, how do I figure out the alto and tenor?

Tags: harmony

[[image: my assignment inb4 Im not gonna do your homework for you]I missed one class and now I don't understand how to do this assignment plz help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gv2Yx.png)

Comment: Is the problem that you don't know what you're supposed to do, or is it that you're having trouble doing it?

Comment: both I kindve know what to \do but at the same time I have no clue

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, as phrased, it is very unlikely to help anyone else.

Comment: I'd love to help but this kind of question isn't covered here. There's a chat channel here that would be a great place to get help. You need a reputation score of 20 to use it, but that can be gained pretty easily. Meanwhile—can you ask your instructor for help? Maybe that's the best bet!

Comment: It kinda seems like either you missed more than one class or that class was four hours long.

Comment: The purpose of assignments is to exercise (and prove, mostly to yourself) knowledge about a subject, in order to have better understanding of its aspects, which are probably fundamental to your learning. If you missed a class and don't understand its assignment, then your problem is not about *that* understanding. Even if we tried to explain what's being asked, you'd still probably be unable to do it, because either you won't understand our explanation, or you don't have means to solve it, and that's exactly because you missed an important class. Ask your schoolmates or, better, your teacher.

Answer (score 3):

In each exercise, the soprano and bass notes either imply specific chords, or the musical context does.

The first exercise for example:

1. Looking at the final two notes, D and F, suggests either a Bb major chord or a D minor chord.
2. Given the key signature of one flat (either F major or D minor), we can conclude the final chord will be D minor.
3. The preceding chord has A and E given, which could be A major or A minor. Since A major is the dominant chord of D minor, we can conclude A major as the correct chord.
4. After repeating this process for the other chords, it just remains to fill out the chords in the alto and tenor using the voice-leading rules that were, presumably, taught in earlier classes.

Comment: is there a youtube video you could direct me toward that has more in depth information on this because I dont want to like ask too much but I have like 7 new questions stemming from your answer.

Comment: @sillysnail417 This page (https://kaitlinbove.com/voice-leading) looks like a good starting place.